Refreshing webapp session while using OIDC
I'm trying to use OIDC based integration for SSO in my Webapp. The idea is that anyone deploying the app should be able to plugin OIDC configuration (wellknow url, client id and secret) and can configure any OIDC provider, like Okta, Auth0, PingID, etc. My webapp is an SPA with a backend server side API. I use Authorization flow to get the id and access token.
Once I get the access token successfully, we use our own JWT token which the SPA uses to talk to the APIs. The JWT approach is already used in the app, before the OIDC integration.
Although I won't need to access any of the API Endpoints exposed by the OIDC provider, I decided the based the apps JWT expiration based on the access token. And use the refresh token to refresh the session in the SPA.
I was under the impression that the access token's TTL can be configured easily in the OIDC provider, but that doesn't seem to be the case. The idea was to keep the access token's ttl low and use the refresh token frequently.
It looks like one cannot set the TTL of access token that easily in the OIDC configuration. It seems the access token's ttl is tied to the packing and usage of the API's by the provider, see e.g.:
https://community.auth0.com/t/need-help-changing-token-expiration-time-in-authentication-api-response/104251/7
https://support.pingidentity.com/s/question/0D5Do00000iPpHEKA0/how-to-customise-the-access-token-expiry-duration-in-pingone
Is the idea of using the access token's expiry to manage session not a correct one?
Should I use the ID Token's expiration, it seems wrong, since it can't really be used for accessing any resources as such.
Am I misunderstanding any key points in OIDC?

SHORT ANSWER
A client's session time against APIs is determined by the lifetime of the refresh token, so you need to use one in your client to API flows.
Yet how to get one is very much deployment related. So I explain a couple of options below.
AS TO IDP DEPLOYMENT MODEL
By issuing your own JWT ypu are acting like an authorization server (AS), which is used in flows like this:

Client runs a code flow to the AS
AS runs a code flow to an identity provider (IDP) which issues a set of tokens to the AS
AS then issues a set of tokens to the client

This enables your apps and APIs to receive consistent tokens regardless of the IDP used:

The client then sends short lived (AS issued) access tokens to its APIs
The user's session time is represented by the lifetime of the (AS issued) refresh token

In this model, customers typically only need to run a browser
AS DEPLOYMENT MODEL
Another possibility is to write a standards based app that can use any AS, where the customer supplies the AS.
In such a case, you should not issue your own JWT and the app should use the AS tokens directly. Again, the session time is represented by the AS refresh token.
In practice this is a difficult deployment model:

You run into the type of vendor differences or limitations that you mention in your question

Detailed configuration such as that for access token lifetime and claims, must be done in each AS and there are greater demands on your customers

You typically need to deploy all components, including APIs, to each customer, all of which point to the customer AS


